# How can I sort this bidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a conditional that gives my array the value of 2 if its empty otherwise the value will be 1, what I want is to sort this bidimensinal by the value of the associative index for example

```
$arr[$n]["key"] = 1;
$arr[$n]["key"] = 1;
$arr[$n]["key"] = 1;
$arr[$n]["key"] = 2;
$arr[$n]["key"] = 2;
```

What I want to do is first print the number 1's and then the number 2's

I've tried all the methods on this page and nothing works.. please help me. Thanks!

Comment: *I've tried all the methods* - show us what you've tried

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you posted will result in an array with only two values. What is there to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort your array with asort, quick example:

```
<?php

$arr[0][1] = 1;
$arr[0][2] = 1;
$arr[0][3] = 2;
$arr[0][4] = 2;
$arr[0][5] = 1;

asort($arr[0]);

var_dump($arr[0]);
```

Then you can foreach sort this array with a loop;

Answer (score 0):

There is a very cool table to choose the function for the excepted result:

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php